# How to print empty when ListView is empty? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget, runtime-error

I want to print empty when ListView.builder is empty (when I do not have data in Firebase) and I am using FutureBuilder.

Also, I am retrieving this data from Firebase. I want to do that to avoid this error when I do not have data in firebase "NoSuchMethodeError: The method 'forEach' was called on null".

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: retrieve.once(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          lists.clear();
          print("object");
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
          values.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
          });

          return new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: lists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Text(
                            "\$" + lists[index]["amount"],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'FjallaOne'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      lists[index]["title"] + " " + lists[index]["Picker"],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'FjallaOne'),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      lists[index]["Date"],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        }

        return SpinKitHourGlass(
          color: Colors.purple,
          size: 70.0,
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Don't want to post this as answer. You can just add a condition to check if the "lists" is empty before returning your ListView. " if( lists.isEmpty ) return Container(); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect lists could either be empty or null. So just add this condition before you return a ListView.

```
 if(lists?.isEmpty || lists == null)return Center(child: Text("Empty"));
```

NOTE: The question mark after `lists` makes sure it doesn't throw an error if lists is null.

Your code should now look like this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: retrieve.once(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          lists.clear();
          print("object");
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
          values.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
          });

          if(lists?.isEmpty || lists == null)return Center(child: Text("Empty"));
          return new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: lists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Text(
                            "\$" + lists[index]["amount"],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'FjallaOne'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      lists[index]["title"] + " " + lists[index]["Picker"],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'FjallaOne'),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      lists[index]["Date"],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        }

        return SpinKitHourGlass(
          color: Colors.purple,
          size: 70.0,
        );
      },
    );
```

ALSO NOTE: When a list is empty, a `ListView.builder()` will not throw a `noSuchMethodError`. The error is being thrown because the data you're returning from Firestore is null.

There are two possible causes for this. Either the field you are querying for in Firestore does not exist, or you are using the wrong syntax.

Change this:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
```

To this:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data['value'];
```